# How Do I write an IBM (Lotus) Notes Client?

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm looking to write a unified email and messaging program. Supporting IMAP, POP, and SMTP are all pretty easy - the protocols are well documented and easy to come by.

Exchange has a SOAP API documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb409286(v=exchg.140).aspx), whereby you can write an Exchange client which talks with Exchange servers.

I'm looking to find out what protocol IBM (Lotus) Notes uses and how I can go about writing a standalone application which can send and receive mail. (Standalone is a key part of this - I've seen various things about automating the existing client, but I'm looking to write a new client, so I need to know what protocols it uses.)

Language is unimportant to me at this time. I'm leaning towards Python for the project, but I'm still at an exploratory stage where I'm trying to determine what frameworks exist in any language to help me write this.

Comment: Native Notes is both undocumented and crypto-heavy; nothing happens without involving the credentials in the Notes ID in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty interesting topic! There are two ways I can think of that provide mail-oriented abstractions, and two that allow you to access mail files as databases directly.

To start out with, and this is very likely the expedient route to take, Domino supports IMAP. It's far from perfect and it's not likely to improve, but it does more or less work for mail access. Not every server has it enabled by default, but it's not terribly difficult or unusual for an administrator to do so.

Recently, the [Extension Library](http://extlib.openntf.org) has added a JSON-based mail service that purports to provide a pretty friendly API for many operations, but is not complete - for example, it doesn't seem to cover a user's custom views or folders.

Depending on the depth of the project, then there are the routes for accessing the server using Domino's database API, which would be the most flexible but would involve far more hurdles.

The core protocol is [NRPC](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_admin.nsf/2e73cbb2141acefa85256b8700688cea/1d70b1582f278f2d85256c1d0039098a?OpenDocument), which, to my knowledge, is only implemented in the core Notes library. As Stan said, it's heavily tied to the presence of an ID file (server or user) and uses that for its encryption. With some setup, you could have that library and ID present and then use the C functions and structs on a platform it supports. This route would give you the most functionality (there are a number of C-level functions to assist with converting between Notes's document representation and MIME).

Alternatively, there is a remote-access protocol called [DIIOP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/) that can be used to access a remote Domino server using UN/password credentials via Java objects. This is not enabled for every server, but it's not terribly uncommon, and isn't that hard to enable. You wouldn't have access to all of the C API's functionality for edge cases, but this would cover a lot of ground.

Comment: Question: If the user can provide their Notes ID file, can my program just download and set up the official Notes client in the background, then hook up with the C Toolkit? Is there a reason that wouldn't work?

Comment: Technically, sure - you could create the program and data directories and the needed notes.ini file on the fly. Legally, though, I think that'd be a tough pitch. In that situation, it may be safer to just say "you have to install Notes first".

Comment: I thought of an addendum to the ExtLib API: there's also a generic Data REST API that you could potentially use to fill in gaps in the Mail API, but the format would be slightly different and would take some specific DB-level configuring, I think.

Comment: I would not recommend going with the C API Toolkit. That requires in-depth low-level knowledge of Notes architecture. I believe that Python on Windows can access the COM API, which would be a better choice - with the caveat that some features of the API don't work on Win64 and officially IBM doesn't support it on Win64, but enough does work that you should be able to do most of this.  As for downloading the client in background, wouldn't you expect that anyone who has an ID file already has the client anyhow?  (And yes, the client install is required for the COM API, too,)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work in Python, and you are willing to limit yourself to just the most recent versions of the Lotus Domino server, then I think that you should consider using the REST API that is known as the Donmino Data Service. Here's some [on-line documentation](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html).

Comment: Care you elaborate a bit on this? This sounds like it could be better than what I was thinking, but could you give me a minimal example of authenticating, viewing a message, and sending a message? I'll change the accepted answer to yours if you can provide examples. Edit: Hm. Requires some configuration on the server end. IDK who even administrates our server - still worth checking out, though.

Comment: Jesse's answer is more comprehensive, and I see he actually mentioned the REST API in comments, so leave the acceptance there. Anyhow, I'm only suggesting based on general knowledge of the APIs, not based on experience. I don't have any examples I can post, not to mention minimal ones. And yes, it does require some server-side config, but so might some other routes that have been mentioned (e.g., DIIOP) so I thought it worth mentioning.